# Get Columns Names After a Empty Query Result

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm creating an application that receives a generic SQL code and return to the user a result set with columns and query result (Like a MySQL cliente). But when the value result set is empty the hibernate do not run de queryTransformer consequently not find the columns. Is there a way to get only the columns info?

I try to use AliastoEntityMapResultTransformer and use some avaliable methods, but it didn't work.

```java
NativeQuery< ? > query = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
Map<String, Object> queryParams = new TreeMap<>(params);

Optional<RowSelection> rowSelection = getRowSelection(params);
if (rowSelection.isPresent()) {
    query.setFirstResult(rowSelection.get().getFirstRow())
        .setMaxResults(rowSelection.get().getMaxResults());
    queryParams.remove("itemsPerPage");
    queryParams.remove("pageNumber");
}

val queryTransformer = new BookmarkResultHibernateCreator();
queryParams.entrySet().forEach(k -> {
    if (k.getValue() instanceof Collection) {
        Collection< ? > col = (Collection< ? >) k.getValue();
        query.setParameterList(k.getKey(), col);
    } else {
        query.setParameter(k.getKey(), k.getValue());
    }
});


query.setResultTransformer(queryTransformer);
@Cleanup ScrollableResults scroll = query
        .setFetchSize(100)
        .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
        .setReadOnly(true)
        .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
// Força execução da query.
while(scroll.next());
return queryTransformer.getResults();
```

Do not show any error, just do not work as I expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problemn using native SQL form java.sql.*

The entityManager have a method called doWork that recieves a lambda and return a connection, with the connection I've opened a statement. The statament have the method getMetaData() that returns the columns in a array :)

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
```